# Debugging Global name ''QgsMapLayerComboBox' is not defined?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qt-designer, combo-box

I try to develop little plugin for Qgis. I used custom widgets in QT that comes with QGIS 2.18 and loaded QgisMapLayerComboBox. But when I reload my plugin in QGis it gives me an error:

> 2018-01-14T00:06:10   1   Traceback (most recent call last):
>               File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 342, in startPlugin
>                 plugins[packageName].initGui()
>               File "C:/Users/Michal.DESKTOP-M9QN5BH/.qgis2/python/plugins\DMS2Point\DMS2Point.py",
>   line 172, in initGui
>                 parent=self.iface.mainWindow())
>               File "C:/Users/Michal.DESKTOP-M9QN5BH/.qgis2/python/plugins\DMS2Point\DMS2Point.py",
>   line 139, in add_action
>                 self.dlg = DMS2PointDialog()
>               File "C:/Users/Michal.DESKTOP-M9QN5BH/.qgis2/python/plugins\DMS2Point\DMS2Point_dialog.py",
>   line 30, in **init**
>                 self.setupUi(self)
>               File "C:/Users/Michal.DESKTOP-M9QN5BH/.qgis2/python/plugins\DMS2Point\DMS2Point_dialog_base.py",
>   line 48, in setupUi
>                 self.mMapLayerComboBox_2 = QgsMapLayerComboBox(self.widget)             NameError: global name 'QgsMapLayerComboBox' is not defined

I don't understand the last line. Code is compiled and everything, step by step made according to tutorials 'How to make a Qgis plugin...'. This error does no appear when I use 'normal' QT ComboBoxes. I wanted to use Qgis Custom Widgets because they might be easier in use and modification.

Comment: Did you import QgsMapLayerComboBox from DMS2Point_dialog_base.py?

Comment: @user55937 - Please post your _comment_ as an **answer** :)

Comment: @Joseph It wasn't intended to be answer in the comment bloc. It was a genuine question. The answer seemed pretty obvious to me, and so I just wanted to rule it out first.

Answer (score 3):

from within DMS2Point_dialog_base.py add

```
from qgis.gui import QgsMapLayerComboBox
```

Answer (score 2):

So I found the solution for this issue. In Your main .py plugin file (YourPLugin.py) at the beginning type:

```
from YourPluginName_dialog_base import QgsMapLayerComboBox
```