# Retrieving QgsMapLayerComboBox's currently selected layer to get its name for editing in function

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, gui, combo-box

I'm using a qgis plugin with very basic gui with 4 QgsMapLayerComboBoxes, I'll use each one to select a layer. I want to retrieve the currently selected item's name for each combobox (a vector layer) as a variable in my function so I can edit each layer.

As of right now, I added this code to my def run(self) :

```py
self.dlg.mapLayerComboBox1.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.PolygonLayer)
self.dlg.mapLayerComboBox2.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.LineLayer)
self.dlg.mapLayerComboBox3.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.PointLayer)
self.dlg.mapLayerComboBox4.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.PointLayer)
```

In my function I have this `layer1 = mapLayerComboBox1.layer()` (same with other layers), I'm not sure yet how to retrieve the layer's name (to use with `mapLayersByName` similarly to how it would be feasible using `QComboBox.currentText()` something I learned reading [PyQGIS using selected layer from a combobox](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/341430/pyqgis-using-selected-layer-from-a-combobox)) but even before that I receive the following error when I test the plugin:

```
layer1 = mapLayerComboBox1.layer()
NameError: name 'mapLayerComboBox1' is not defined
```

At the start of my MainPlugin.py I added this `from qgis.gui import QgsMapLayerComboBox` following answers from this thread [Debugging Global name ''QgsMapLayerComboBox' is not defined?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267944/debugging-global-name-qgsmaplayercombobox-is-not-defined) but I still get the error. Following the second answer (which advises to use from `YourPluginName_dialog_base import QgsMapLayerComboBox`) I receive a critical error:

```
File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 793, in _import
mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mypluginname_dialog_base'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the selected layer use:

```
selectedlayer = self.dlg.mapLayerComboBox1.currentLayer()
```

Or combined with a filter its:

```
self.dlg.mapLayerComboBox1.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.PointLayer)
selectedlayer = self.dlg.mapLayerComboBox1.currentLayer()
```

In case you really want the name, not the layer, you can use

```
selectedlayername = selectedlayer.name()
```

About your Error `NameError: name 'mapLayerComboBox1' is not defined`, you need to reference to your Plugins dialog. If youve done it with PluginBuilder-Plugin, that should be

```
layer1 = self.dlg.mapLayerComboBox1.layer()
```

Note that `.layer()` *Returns the layer currently shown at the specified index within the combo box* as [stated in the docs](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.16/gui/QgsMapLayerComboBox.html#qgis.gui.QgsMapLayerComboBox.layer). So you need to add an integer for the index, such as `.layer(2)`. To get the currently selected layer use `.currentLayer()` instead.

Comment: Thank you it does work perfectly.